# Does Jaeger support Grafana Tempo backend?

Tags: grafana, jaeger, tempodb

im starting with tracing tools. I would like to use Grafana Tempo backend storage and as UI Jaeger. Is possible that this stack will work together? Im running that in docker via official docker-compose files.

I checked Jaeger documentation and did not find anything about Grafana Tempo support. There is only Elastic, Cassandra, Fluxdb etc... but not Grafana Tempo.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember when you use Tempo (or Loki) that these systems do not index data. This is why they are so inexpensive; the challenge is that you cannot do a full text search across the data in bulk, this is why Jaeger does not support Tempo as a backend. The way all the Grafana projects work is that when you troubleshoot you start with a metric, isolate down to a small timeframe or specific component, then pivot to logs or traces. Unfortunately, when troubleshooting there are lots of good reasons to start with logs or traces, but this is not possible with their backends, this is the tradeoff between indexing and not indexing, which is why they are inexpensive to operate in comparison to OpenSearch/ElasticSearch.